# How to get data XML into a table from a list of books sheet

Tags: xml, xslt, xpath

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="books.xsl"?>
<bookList>
    <Book BookId="3311">
        <BookName>Flying</BookName>
        <readerList>
            <readers sid="1001">Ashley</readers>
            <readers sid="1002">Mark</readers>
            <readers sid="1003">Donar</readers>
        </readerList>
        <readingItems>
            <readings name="Assign 4" weight="20">
                <mark studId="1001">15</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">18</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">9</mark>
            </readings>
            <readings name="Assign 5" weight="25">
                <mark studId="1001">23</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">14</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">23</mark>
            </readings>
            <readings name="Essay" weight="15">
                <mark studId="1001">13</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">12</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">6</mark>
            </readings>
            <readings name="Exam" weight="40">
                <mark studId="1001">38</mark>
                <mark studId="1002">25</mark>
                <mark studId="1003">20.5</mark>
            </readings>
        </readingItems>
    </Book>
</bookList>
```

That is the data for the books. I can't change the format. I don't know how to work with readersList into readers. It doesn't seem to work no matter what I do.

This is my xsl sheet

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1" ?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total Mark</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="bookList/Book/readerList"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="readerList">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="readers/@sid"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="readers"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I want it obviously in the format that I specified, but no matter what I do I cannot get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

One problem you have is your XML has `readerList` but your XSLT has `readersList`. Also, you only have one `readerList` but it looks like you want the code within the template matching it to output once for each `reader`, so you might want to select `reader` elements instead.

Try this XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total Mark</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="bookList/Book/readerList/readers"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="readers">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@sid"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(../../readingItems/readings/mark[@studId = current()/@sid])"/></td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Note I also showed how to get the total mark, although this could be improved with the use of an `xsl:key`.

This assumes there are multiple books in your XML, and you want results separated by book:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">

  <xsl:key name="marksByBook" match="mark" use="concat(../../../@BookId, '|', @studId)" />

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <html>
      <body>
        <table border="1">
          <tr>
            <th>ID</th>
            <th>Name</th>
            <th>Total Mark</th>
            <th>Grade</th>
          </tr>
          <xsl:apply-templates select="bookList/Book/readerList/readers"/>
        </table>
      </body>
    </html>
  </xsl:template>
  <xsl:template match="readers">
    <tr>
    <td><xsl:value-of select="@sid"/></td>
     <td><xsl:value-of select="."/></td>
      <td><xsl:value-of select="sum(key('marksByBook', concat(../../@BookId, '|', @sid)))"/></td>
      <td>?</td>
    </tr>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Taking into account the `weight` might be more troublesome, and would probably warrant a new question...